# Is it possible to modify a cp_sat model after construction?

Tags: or-tools, constraint-programming, cp-sat

I have a model for finding a particular class of integer numbers (the "Keith numbers"), which works well, but is quite slow as it requires constructing a new model many times. Is there a way to update a model, in particular to change the coefficient in the constraint. In other words, change the model to match a different `mat`, without reconstructing the whole thing?

```py
def _construct_model(self, mat):
  model = cp_model.CpModel()
  digit = [model.NewIntVar(0, 9, f'digit[{i}]') for i in range(self.k)]

  # Creates the constraint.
  model.Add(sum([mat[i] * digit[i] for i in range(self.k)]) == 0)

  model.Add(digit[0] != 0)
  return model, digit
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, but you are on your own.

You can access the underlying `cp_model_proto` protobuf from the model, and modify it directly.

We have no plan currently to add a modification API on top of the `cp_model` API.